# how to test if a object was created with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

How to test a method that creates 10 objects User with rspec, but returns a boolean value?

And if it was only one user? There is a cleaner way to test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to test that 10 `User` records were created you could use the `expect` matcher

```
expect { my_magic_method }.to change { User.count }.by(10)
```

and if you also want to test that it returns true

```
expect(my_magic_method).to be_true
```

[official documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change)